# how to set custom marker window to specific marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to set a custom info window to an specific marker in Android. Lets say that I have two types of markers and I just want the custom info window to take place to a one or a set of markers, but not all markers on the map.

So far I'have try the basic, created a custom layout for the marker and calling the `map.setInfoWindowAdapter()`.

```
 googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker, null);
            TextView info= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info);

            info.setText(marker.getPosition().toString());

            return v;
        }
    });
```

It affects all markers that are being displayed. Is there a way to specify a marker?

Answer (score 2):

Try with: 
**Compare** marker.getPosition() with yourCustomMarkerPosition then //Do Stuff